# Applying Blur on Body Except Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a blur effect on the entire page whenever a user opens a widget. The blur effect is supposed to apply on the entire page except the opened widget.

I've went ahead and did this:

```
$("body div:not('.header__profile-create-wrapper') ").addClass("blur");
```

Its working, but that widget also has forms elements within it that are also getting blurred. I tried doing the following:

```
$("body div:not('.header__profile-create-wrapper') > * ").addClass("blur");
```

That didn't seem to do the trick. Any clues?

Comment: maybe using body>div:not(..) will do, else it is applied to any div .if a parent is blured, you cannot unblur childs :)

Comment: That did it! Thanks :D. You should put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select direct childs of body, else any div (and their childs) will get blured.

```
$("body > div:not('.header__profile-create-wrapper') ").addClass("blur");
```